# Material 001 and Material 002 how to intertwine them with another environment

Tags: materials

Suppose that I create

```
Material001
```

and

```
Material002
```

in Material Properties and set them to some color.

Can I use this 2 items in other buttons like

Texture Properties, Object Data Properties etc. ? Where and how do I intertwine them with this button ?

Comment: Materials are available in Blender everywhere they need to be. It is hard to understand clearly what you mean.

Comment: What are trying to achieve with that? What do you expect if you will have access to material in texture or object properties?  In some properties you have access to a texture properties, like in displacement modifier or particle system.