# Material001 second attempt

Tags: materials

There are buttons on the r.h.s. of Blender which are starting from bottom:

Material properties

Object Data Properties

Object Constraint Properties

Physics Properties

Particle Properties

etc.

Now, in Material Properties I can add Materials like this:

Material

Material001

Material002

etc.

Now I want to find in which one of the buttons listed above there is a **menu** offering an existing

Material001

so that I can create a link to this particular object named Material001 and make use of it and its properties like color.

Comment: Yes I know this button. But I want other buttons as listed above to see also an existing material Material001. Have you caught me ? i.e. **not** the Material properties but rather "object data properties" or even the others which would offer Material001.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm not sure about that... I'll delete the answer.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Oh I'm happy with your answer, it may well be the case that this is not possible! I had an opposite feeling for a while. So **nowhere** in entire Blender there is a menu like that that would offer Materail001 ?

Comment: Is this the same question you asked earlier? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201835/material-001-and-material-002-how-to-intertwine-them-with-another-environment please read [what should I do if no one answers my question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: P!ease enhance your original post via edit rather then creating a new one. Thank you.

Comment: @vklidu Once put on [Hold] it's indeed difficult to enhance it enough so that it would be re-opened again. I have a feeling that nobody is interested in re-opening.

Comment: What do you mean? Your post I see open https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201835/material-001-and-material-002-how-to-intertwine-them-with-another-environment

Comment: @user3357120 "*Once put on [Hold] it's indeed difficult to enhance it enough so that it would be re-opened again. I have a feeling that nobody is interested in re-opening.*" That is incorrect, edited questions are put on queue for review so they can be reopened, and moderators are made aware of it so they get attention, unlike posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question about the other property windows, what you may be looking for is the shader editor.  You can access it by going to the shading workspace at the top, and you'll find the bottom window is already set up for editing materials.

[image]

This MAY be related to what you're wanting, because you can access UV coordinates here, etc.

Comment: Finally someone has understood what I meant! Thank you.